# I have a case how to create alert dialog with function back to previous activity,

Tags: android, layout

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setTitle("judul")
   .setMessage("NOTE : TEKAN TOMBOL SUARA SEPERTI GAMBAR DIATAS PADA LAYAR BERIKUT")
   .setIcon(R.drawable.sound)
   .setNeutralButton("OKE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
      }
   }).show();
```

Comment: u mean you want to return to the previous activity when the above `NeutralButton` is clicked?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please Read this 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17503